# C++ Allocating large maps on the stack vs heap when the data is known at compile time

Tags: c++, memory-management, unordered-map

I've read conflicting ideas about what to do with large unordered maps, whether to allocate them on the heap vs the stack depending on its size being known/not at compile time. So hopefully someone can clear this up once and for all, because even as I've tried to move my large map to the heap, visual studio still warns me about it needing to be put on the heap.

defs.cpp

`unordered_map<string, string>* Keywords = new unordered_map<string, string>({...});`

defs.h

`extern unordered_map<string, string>* Keywords;`

The map has a size of 55k and is defined in the code and will never change as the app runs.
I repeat, the app never edits this map, it never adds to it, it never removes from it. the pairs are set in the defs.cpp file as described, before the code is compiled, the list is there. That's why I put [...] as placeholder to avoid pasting 1000+ lines of text.
I repeat, the example is exactly as described, this is the minimum reproductible example, there are no other parts required, this is 100% of the code you need.
It just needs to exist and be accessible to many parts of the app. From what I understand, the `new` keyword should already be allocating on the heap?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

edit: for reference here's the warning shown by Visual Studio

```
C6262: Function uses '55360' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'..
This allocation was for a compiler-generated temporary for 'struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>const,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char>>[865] at line XXX. 
Consider moving some data to heap.
```

Comment: Are you worried about the *contents* of the map (i.e. someone inserting a million elements) or about the map object *itself* (ie. the value returned by `sizeof(unordered_map)`)?

Comment: `std::unordered_map` will by default put all but small amount of data on the heap, ie `sizeof(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>)` is fixed no matter how much data is added to it.

Comment: 99.99999999999999% of the time `unordered_map<string, string>* Keywords = new unordered_map<string, string>({...});` is not what you want.  standard containers aren't that large, they normally are just wrappers around some pointers.

Comment: You're mixing `unordered_map` object itself with the contents of `unordered_map`. No matter where `unordered_map` is, the contents will be on heap unless you use a custom allocator.

Comment: @ComicSansMS The map will always be 55k and is defined in defs.cpp in the code, and nothing will be added or removed from the map while the app runs.

RichardCritten Ok, but VS is still warning me about it. Is it wrong?

NathanOliver I'm open to changing this, since this part of the code isn't heavily referenced yet. I need to get a value by string key, what alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: @LAZ _"I've read conflicting ideas about what to do with large unordered maps..."_: where have you read this?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, you define a map like I mentioned above, with 55k bytes of data. Visual Studio will then show a warning (green squiggly line) about it.
Here's the warning: "C6262: Function uses '55360' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.. This allocation was for a compiler-generated temporary for 'struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>>const,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char>>[865] at line XXX. Consider moving some data to heap."

Comment: Re: "VS is still warning me about it" -- what does the warning say?

Comment: @PeteBecker Comment above yours, added it to the post as well 

Comment: Which function and what is `XXX`?

Comment: @Evg It isn't in a function, it in defs.cpp. It says at line XXX. clearly, that's the line number.

Comment: @LAZ please [edit] your question and put all relevant information into the question, not in a comment. But specially a [mcve] is still needed

Comment: @Jabberwocky Pretty simple concept, literally you make two files and you put what I said above. That's it. What is missing? I'm not going to put thousands of lines of text in the post when [...] is pretty clear, that's where the pairs go.

Comment: `XXX` is the line number of `unordered_map<string, string>* Keywords = new unordered_map<string, string>({...});`? What is `...`? You're omitting all relevant details...

Comment: Guessing (as no [mcve]): you used an initialiser list to initialise the `unordered_map`.  The initialise list will be on the stack __not__ the unordered_map data post initialisation.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, the list is defined before it's even compiled. The app never adds or removes anything from it. It's 100% unchanging. Ok, so what can I do to fix it, if it *is* putting it on the stack? Much appreciated

Comment: @LAZ _"That's it. What is missing?"_. A [mcve] is missing. A [mcve] is not a _description_ of some minimal code but _some minimal code_.

Comment: @LAZ reffering to `C6262: Function uses '55360' bytes of stack: `. We really need to see this function, at least the relevant parts of it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Dude, this is  100% of the code. I challenge you to find anything missing from the example that is missing aside from the 1000+ pairs that you could easily generate on your own.

Again, for your last comment. It isn't in a function. There's only this map in the file. That's it, no functions no nothing.

Comment: @LAZ would [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dnoncWsjx) be a [mcve] (just 2 map entries instead of 1000 or so in your actual code) for your case?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yep, my pairs are { "like": "this" }, but yeah. That's all of it.

Comment: `...` is neither minimal nor reproducible. Something like `{"aaa", "a"}, {"aab", "a"}, ..., {"zzz", "a"}` instead of just `...` would be much clearer instead of all those words. To make a truly reproducible example you could use simple macros.

Comment: @Evg Thanks captain tedium, I think just the same as I could do that, you can read one sentence that summarizes exactly that.

Comment: @LAZ generally it's better to provide code rather than describing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler warning is not about the hash map, it’s about the initial data for the map, which you put inside your `({...})`. That code allocates an object of type `std::initializer_list<something>`, that object contains a long array, and that array is on the stack.

Consider moving that initialization data somewhere else, here’s an example.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace
{
    // Initial data for the map
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    static std::pair<std::string, std::string> s_mapInitialData[] =
    {
        {"key1"s, "value1"s},
        {"key2"s, "value2"s},
    };

    // Create a hash map from the above data.
    // Calling this function destroys the data in s_mapInitialData array
    // The strings are being moved from there into the new map
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> createTheMap()
    {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> res;
        res.reserve( std::size( s_mapInitialData ) );
        for( auto& p : s_mapInitialData )
            res.emplace( std::move( p ) );
        return res;
    }
}

// Call this function to get the const reference to the hash map
// This function is thread-safe, BTW.
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& getTheMap()
{
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map = createTheMap();
    return map;
}
```

Comment: This explains exactly why vs is warning, thank you.
I assume I can just call createTheMap immediately in that file and use the ref to it elsewhere too ?

Comment: Call whenever you want. The first time you call the function will reshape the data into the hash map. Next time you call the function, it will return the object which was already there, in that static function-local variable. In modern C++ language the runtime even guarantees thread safety of that thing: when two threads call `getTheMap` at the same time, one of them will run `createTheMap`, another thread will sleep on some mutex waiting for the result.

Comment: `sizeof( s_mapInitialData ) / sizeof( s_mapInitialData[ 0 ] )` -> `std::size( s_mapInitialData )` or just `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> res(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(s_mapInitialData)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(s_mapInitialData)));`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_map<K,V>` must allocate the storage for its elements dynamically. To see why, you can for example consider that `sizeof(std::unordered_map<K,V>)` is a compile time constant. The elements are not stored directly within the map object but elsewhere.

The same is true for most other containers (`std::array` is an exception). Hence, you almost never need to dynamically allocate the container.

(And just assumed you did, then you would not use `new` and raw pointers.)

Answer (score 0):

I will risk a glimpse into the crystal ball. When you write

```
unordered_map<string, string>* Keywords =
    new unordered_map<string, string>({...});
```

Then you actually have an enormous number of values between the brackets in `{...}`. These values are allocated on the stack no matter how you allocate the `unordered_map`. Without knowing what you actually have there, it is next to impossible to suggest suitable workarounds.

Comment: I do yes, the list is known and set before the code is compiled.
not sure what you mean about not knowing what I have there, the types are string, string.
So it's just 1000+ string, string pairs.